# Scale div on hover inside of an table td not on top of the document

Tags: html, css

I tried to make a JSFiddle, but I wasn't able to do it because it had totally different behaviour than the code in Chrome, and I couldn't fix it.

Here's my example:

```css
body {
  margin-left: 50;
  margin-top: 50;
}

.innerRel {
  background: #ff0000;
  width: 50;
  height: 50;
  margin-bottom: 5;
  text-align: center;
}

.innerRel:hover {
  transform: scale(2.0);
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #00ff00;
}

.outter {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 200;
  width: 150;
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>1.0</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>1.1</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>2.0</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>2.1</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>3.0</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>3.1</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>4.0</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>4.1</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>5.0</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>5.1</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>6.0</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="innerRel">
          <p>6.1</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

My problem is if I hover on a div, I can't see the whole div anymore. **How can I set the div in front of everything?**

I tried to use position:absolute, but it has a strange behaviour when I start scrolling.

Comment: css `transform` maybe can help? `transform: scale(1.2)`

Comment: thats what im using, but it doesnt work like i want it to work, cause i cant see the whole scaled div